# Подсчитать и вывести дубликаты значений в JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, list

есть список с объектами JSON типа:

```
[{'id':'1', 'name':'ivan'},{'id':'2', 'name':'igor'},{'id':'3', 'name':'petr'}]
```

Мне нужно найти все повторяющиеся имена 'name' и вывести попарно (или даже больше- если совпадений больше), мол вот первый объект, вот второй, третий, четвертый..., имена одинаковые.
Вижу решение по очереди добавлять объект в новый список, потом сравнивать с исходным, и если есть совпадения `'name'`- делать `print`, потом очищать новый список и так далее, но чувствую есть решение лаконичнее

вывод хотелось бы такой:

```
{'id':'1', 'name':'ivan'}
{'id':'5', 'name':'ivan'}
{'id':'88', 'name':'ivan'}

{'id':'45', 'name':'igor'}
{'id':'61', 'name':'igor'}
{'id':'1', 'name':'igor'}
{'id':'666', 'name':'igor'}

{'id':'56', 'name':'petr'}
{'id':'89', 'name':'petr'}
...
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/group-list-of-dictionary-data-by-particular-key-in-python/amp/

Comment: @alexey-ten группировка работает, но как сделать вывод только значений, где есть повторы?
# define a function for key
def key_func(k):
    return k['company']
 
# sort INFO data by 'company' key.
INFO = sorted(INFO, key=key_func)
 
for key, value in groupby(INFO, key_func):
    print(key)
    print(list(value))

Comment: Ну так никто не мешает проверить количество элементов в списке перед выводом.

Comment: @alexey-ten как я понимаю там не создается список, а какой то объект модуля groupby

Comment: Ну вы же умеете получать из него список. Хотя вот тут есть более эффективный способ https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384573/1016033

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывел следующее решение, краткое

```
from collections import Counter

name_counts = Counter(item["name"] for item in data)
result = sorted([item for item in data if name_counts[item["name"]] > 1],key = lambda x: x['name'])

print(result)
```

Под `data` имеется в виду следующий набор данных

```
data = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "ivan"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "igor"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "petr"},
    {"id": "4", "name": "ivan"},
    {"id": "5", "name": "igor"},
    {"id": "6", "name": "maria"},
    {"id": "7", "name": "anna"},
    {"id": "8", "name": "alex"},
    {"id": "9", "name": "maria"},
    {"id": "10", "name": "max"},
    {"id": "11", "name": "elena"},
    {"id": "12", "name": "pavel"},
    {"id": "13", "name": "elena"},
    {"id": "14", "name": "natalia"},
    {"id": "15", "name": "dmitry"}
]
```

Результат работы (вывод в терминале)

```
[{'id': '11', 'name': 'elena'}, {'id': '13', 'name': 'elena'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'igor'}, {'id': '5', 'name': 'igor'}, {'id': '1', 'name': 'ivan'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'ivan'}, {'id':
'6', 'name': 'maria'}, {'id': '9', 'name': 'maria'}]
```

---

p.s. если ваша цель заключается в удалении дубликатов, то можно и не сортировать

```
from collections import Counter

name_counts = Counter(item["name"] for item in data)
result = [item for item in data if name_counts[item["name"]] > 1]

print(result)
```

Результат:

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'ivan'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'igor'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'ivan'}, {'id': '5', 'name': 'igor'}, {'id':
'6', 'name': 'maria'}, {'id': '9', 'name': 'maria'}, {'id': '11', 'name': 'elena'}, {'id': '13', 'name': 'elena'}]
```

---

А чтобы вывод был таким же как и у вас, то можно так

```
from collections import Counter

name_counts = Counter(item["name"] for item in data)
result = sorted([item for item in data if name_counts[item["name"]] > 1],key = lambda x: x['name'])

n = result[0]['name']  # Здесь мы инициализируем переменную 'n' значением имени первого элемента в списке 'result'.
for item in result:
    # Далее идет цикл, который проходит по каждому элементу 'item' в списке 'result'.
    
    # В этой строке мы проверяем, равно ли имя текущего элемента 'item' имени, хранящемуся в переменной 'n'.
    # Если имена совпадают, то мы просто выводим 'item', иначе добавляем пустую строку перед выводом элемента 'item'.
    print(item if n == item['name'] else f'\n{item}')
    
    # Здесь мы обновляем значение переменной 'n' новым именем текущего элемента 'item'.
    n = item['name']
```

Вывод в терминале:

```
{'id': '11', 'name': 'elena'}
{'id': '13', 'name': 'elena'}

{'id': '2', 'name': 'igor'}
{'id': '5', 'name': 'igor'}

{'id': '1', 'name': 'ivan'}
{'id': '4', 'name': 'ivan'}

{'id': '6', 'name': 'maria'}
{'id': '9', 'name': 'maria'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```py
data = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'ivan'},
    ...
]

names = {}

# Сохраняем все словари с одинаковыми ключами `name` в один список
for person in data:
    if person['name'] not in names.keys():
        names[person['name']] = []
    names[person['name']].append(person)

# Выводим списки
for name, people in names.items():
    print(*people, sep='\n')
    print()
```

Вывод:

```
{'id': '1', 'name': 'ivan'}
{'id': '5', 'name': 'ivan'}
...

{'id': '45', 'name': 'igor'}
{'id': '61', 'name': 'igor'}
...

{'id': '56', 'name': 'petr'}
...
```

Только вот в конце выводится пустая строка, но я думаю, это не страшно.

Comment: а как оставить только дубли, где name повторяется > 1 раза?